# Terraform modules argument VAR is required, but no definition was found

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-modules, terraform-aws-modules

I have Terraform modules to provision AWS resources. After `terraform plan`, I see the following error:

*Error: Missing required argument
on main.tf line 113, in module "ecs-task-execution-role":
113: module "ecs-task-execution-role" {
The argument "iam_role_name" is required, but no definition was found.*

Here is my resource defined in `../terraform/modules/iam/ecs_iam.tf`:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam--task-execution-role" {
  name               = var.iam_role_name
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs-task-assume-role.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs-task-assume-role" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "ecs-task-execution-role" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

# Attach the above policy to the execution role.

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs-task-execution-role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.iam-task-execution-role.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.ecs-task-execution-role.arn
}
```

Variables are defined in `../terraform/modules/iam/variables.tf`:

```
variable "iam_role_name" {
  type = string
}
```

The module is in `../terraform/production/main.tf`:

```
module "iam-jo-task-execution-role" {

  source = "../modules/iam"

  iam_role_name = "iam-jo-task-execution-role"

}

# Attach the above policy to the execution role.

module "ecs-task-execution-role" {

  source = "../modules/iam"

}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which file(s) is for module located in `../modules/iam`?

Comment: The path was incorrect above.Yes, it's `../modules/iam` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I misunderstood resources and modules in Terraform.

In the `../terraform/production/main.tf` file that declares the use of resources found in the source `../modules/iam`, I needed the following syntax:

```
module "iam-jo-task-execution-role" {

  source = "../modules/iam"

  iam_role_name = "iam-jo-task-execution-role"

}
```

There is no need to define a module for each resource declared in `../terraform/modules/iam/ecs_iam.tf`. This is just a grouping (packaging) of several resources.

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

```
module "iam-jo-task-execution-role" {

  source = "../modules/iam"

  iam_role_name = "iam-jo-task-execution-role"

}

# Attach the above policy to the execution role.

module "ecs-task-execution-role" {

  source = "../modules/iam"

}
```

You are not passing a value for the `iam_role_name` variable to the `ecs-task-execution-role` module. The `iam-jo-task-execution-role` module right above it shows how to pass a variable to the module.